# Creating a file and streaming in data on Apache Beam/Google Cloud Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I've not found any documentation or any other questions/answers for my use case. I thought I would post a question.

On Apache Beam/Google Cloud Dataflow, I need to receive a PubSub Message, generate a dynamic query from BigQuery based on information from this message, pull rows from BigQuery containing batchIDs, create one file per batchID on Google Cloud Storage, and then stream in the rows to the batchID files. For each BigQuery row (represented as JSON strings), I would check its batchID and then add it to the correct batchID file as a new line.

I figured out the PubSub and BigQuery stuff. I'm now at the stage in which I've got a PCollection of Strings (each string is a row from BigQuery; the strings are grouped by a batchID).

I would like to:

1. look at the batchID from each string, as it comes in
2. if a file does not exist for this batchID, create a new file, else, do nothing
3. add each string to a new line in the file corresponding to its batchID

In other words, I would like to create a file for each batchID and stream the strings to these files, as they come in. I would really like to avoid aggregating all the batchID strings together in memory (it could be GBs of data) and then writing to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a `GroupByKey` on the batchID, then iterate over the values writing the file. The iterable of a `GroupByKey` need not fit into memory.

Note that if you're writing files you may need to write to a temporary location and then do a rename to make things idempotent.

Comment: Thanks @robertwb - I think this is the right answer, but I keep running into issues setting a Window. PubSubIO locks me into an unbounded PCollection. I didn't realize it would be an issue, when I wrote the question. I wish there were some way to convert from an unbounded PCollection to a bounded PCollection.

Comment: If you're reading from PubSub, you intrinsically have an unbounded PCollection, because there's no way to know you've ever read all the data if the PCollection (or associated with a given key) as more data may be written later. You can know you've seen all the data up to a given point in time, hence the need for windows. If there is a relationship between batchids and time (e.g. they are bounded in time) you could look at using sessions or a custom window fn. Basically, you have to know when you've seen all the data for a given batch id.

Comment: Thanks @robertwb. I had what I thought to be a good idea. I thought I could create a window pane for each PubSub message. Unfortunately, even with a window in place for each message, the PCollection remains unbounded. When one message spawns many database records, and I add those records to a PCollection one at a time, I've now got to create a second window to properly collect these records. In my view, I really shouldn't need another window, the PCollection should be bounded, once a window has been set, but the initial unbounded PubSub PCollection remains locked in.

Comment: A bounded PCollection is one to which nothing more can be added. PubSub reads don't have this property, because one can always publish more to a PubSub topic.